# What lines of code are necessary to reload the PFQueryTableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, reload

I'm using Xcode with Parse.com database for storing data! My question is which lines of code will allow a PFQueryTableViewController to reload?

Answer (score 1):

Parses tables are no different than any other table. You reload it like a normal UITableView. 
I would highly recommend reviewing their documentation.  They are fantastic at providing you well documented resources even dumbing it down to 1st grade level when it comes to implementing push notifications etc and have even helped translate to swift. Don't take them for granted. Their docs are listed here:

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide

Additionally, there are numerous tutorials out there that will set you up for success you just have to go do the research. This question has been duplicated numerous times but my response is too big for a comment. No credit is necessary. Essentially, just do some research.

Here is a link to appcoda. Based on your question I feel you might have some more questions in the future pertaining to parse, no disrespect. Just here to help. I encourage you to review them and hopefully learn from it.

http://www.appcoda.com/tag/pfquerytableviewcontroller/

Happy coding-